# Ramanujacharya and Ramayana

Tags: scripture, ramayana, ramanujacharya

Ramanujacharya faced hassles to hear Ramayana. From whom he faced the difficulty and of what type and what was the reason for it? Finally he heard the Ramayana from that person.

Answer (score 3):

> Ramanujacharya wanted to hear Ramayana from his uncle Periya Thirumalai Nambi. Ramanujacharya was in kancheepuram and Periya Thirumai Nambi in Tirupathi. Those days transportation was not that much advanced. Ramanujacharya came by walk from Kancheepuram to Tirupati and requested to tell Ramayana to him. His uncle said ***not now  come afterwards***. Like that 17 times he sent back Ramanujacharya. Eighteenth time Ramanujacharya came and asked. This time also he denied . When Ramanujacharya was about to leave Periya Nambi called him and said I will tell Ramayana to you. You have got so much patience to hear Ramayana from me. The vedas are in 18 forms in Ramayana and by seeing your patience I am delighted and will certainly tell. Ramanujacharya heard the Ramayana from his uncle.

**Source  Veda Raman by Mukkur Lakshmi Narasimhacharyar and Sri Ramanujacharya**

Comment: You can also add the story of how Ramanujar climed Seshachala with his knees because he didn't want to disrespect Adi Sesha, and how Periya Thirumalai Nambi explained how walking on the hill is not a disrespect to Perumal or Adi Sesha.

Comment: I'll just copy and paste what you wrote in the comment section of [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15241/3872) - "Where are your wordings? It is just copy and paste", bring a change in yourself before you embark on a mission to change the world.

Comment: @chinmay--It is my own wordings  not like you mentioned--you try first and speak  or do not comment  just read and go--